# How to match data on separate sheet then return adjacent data to the cell matched?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, worksheet-function

I have data in A1 in 'sheet1'.

I have data in A1 and C1 on 'sheet2'.

The result and formula will be in cell B1 in 'sheet1'.

I need the formula in cell B1 on 'sheet1' to match up A1 (sheet1) to A1 on sheet2 (that's the easy bit! I can do that no problems with the lookup and reference tab) but instead I want the return value to match up A1 on sheet2 but return the value from C1 on sheet2 instead.

I can't do this, please help?

Comment: Take a look at the `VLOOKUP` function.

Comment: OP was a SO member for less than an hour?...

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!A:C,3,FALSE)`